# how can i paging search james email on Java

Tags: java, email, james

I get the `IMAPFolder` object. Can pass `folder.getMessages(start, end);` Gets paging data, but the search method is not implemented.How can I do？

```
// pagable
Message[] messages = folder.getMessages(start, end);
// unPagable
Message[] messages = folder.search(searchTerm);
```

I structured the messages into collections and paginated them, but this was inefficient and I expected ImapFolder to have its own method.

```
emailListDTOList = emailListDTOList.stream().sorted(EmailListDTO.getComparator()).collect(Collectors.toList());   
emailListDTOList = emailListDTOList.subList(start, end);
```